# Check if the attribute is correct and then get the text from <td> using Xpath

Tags: xpath

I'm kind of new to using Xpath, we  use a software to read excel documents which creates a **HTML** based document. The document code looks something like below,

**Code:**

```
<tr height=17 style='height:12.75pt'>
  <td height=17 class=xl153961 style='height:12.75pt'></td>
  <td colspan=2 class=xl773961 dir=LTR width=124 style='width:93pt'>Stat.No.</td>
  <td colspan=2 class=xl773961 dir=LTR width=184 style='width:138pt'>Origin</td>
  <td colspan=3 class=xl773961 dir=LTR width=205 style='width:154pt'>Description</td>
  <td class=xl773961 dir=LTR width=67 style='width:50pt'>Qty</td>
  <td class=xl773961 dir=LTR width=56 style='width:42pt'>kg tot</td>
  <td colspan=2 class=xl773961 dir=LTR width=88 style='width:66pt'>Price</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=17 style='height:12.75pt'>
  <td height=17 class=xl153961 style='height:12.75pt'></td>
  <td class=xl153961></td>
  <td class=xl153961></td>
  <td class=xl153961></td>
  <td class=xl153961></td>
  <td colspan=3 class=xl773961 width=205 style='width:154pt'>Outdoor clothes</td>
  <td class=xl783961 width=67 style='width:50pt'>3</td>
  <td class=xl793961 width=56 style='width:42pt'>0,09</td>
  <td colspan=2 class=xl793961 width=88 style='width:66pt'>55,50</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=17 style='height:12.75pt'>
  <td height=17 class=xl153961 style='height:12.75pt'></td>
  <td colspan=2 class=xl773961 width=124 style='width:93pt'>42032990</td>
  <td colspan=2 class=xl773961 width=184 style='width:138pt'>China</td>
  <td colspan=3 class=xl773961 width=205 style='width:154pt'>Outdoor clothes</td>
  <td class=xl783961 width=67 style='width:50pt'>1</td>
  <td class=xl793961 width=56 style='width:42pt'>0,17</td>
  <td colspan=2 class=xl793961 width=88 style='width:66pt'>134,95</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=17 style='height:12.75pt'>
  <td height=17 class=xl153961 style='height:12.75pt'></td>
  <td colspan=2 class=xl773961 width=124 style='width:93pt'>61033300</td>
  <td colspan=2 class=xl773961 width=184 style='width:138pt'>China</td>
  <td colspan=3 class=xl773961 width=205 style='width:154pt'>Outdoor clothes</td>
  <td class=xl783961 width=67 style='width:50pt'>1</td>
  <td class=xl793961 width=56 style='width:42pt'>0,60</td>
  <td colspan=2 class=xl793961 width=88 style='width:66pt'>110,31</td>
 </tr>
```

I managed to create a Xpath which would look under a given text string and then extracts the data values. Also this software uses **Xpath 1.0**.

**Code:**

```
/html/body/div/table/tr[position() > count(/html/body/div/table/tr[contains(.,'Description')]/preceding-sibling::tr)+1]/td[position() = count(/html/body/div/table/tr/td[contains(.,'Description')]/preceding-sibling::td)+1]
```

Problem I have is this, the documents sometimes have split columns which look like in the below image.
[image: Revo Excel]

When the software creates the **HTML** document it adds 1 extra empty column like in the example below.

**Code:**

```
<tr height=17 style='height:12.75pt'>
<td height=17 class=xl153961 style='height:12.75pt'></td>
<td class=xl153961></td>
<td class=xl153961></td>
<td class=xl153961></td>
<td class=xl153961></td>
<td colspan=3 class=xl773961 width=205 style='width:154pt'>Outdoor clothes</td>
<td class=xl783961 width=67 style='width:50pt'>3</td>
<td class=xl793961 width=56 style='width:42pt'>0,09</td>
<td colspan=2 class=xl793961 width=88 style='width:66pt'>55,50</td>
</tr>
```

So when I use the above Xpath it sees an empty cell under the description column which is not the actual case. As you guys can see in the screen capture there is a description under the description heading.

So what I initially wanted to do is to check if the td was empty or not and if not empty extract the value. I did create something but it didn't work (I think it's not correct).

**Code:**

```
/html/body/div/table/tr[position() > count(/html/body/div/table/tr[contains(.,'Description')]/preceding-sibling::tr)+1]/td [concat(substring(position() = count(/html/body/div/table/tr/td[contains(.,'Description')/preceding-sibling::td)+1),1,number(substring-after(/*/td, 'colspan') * string-length($1))]
```

Then I tried to check for the colspan attribute which is equal to 3. I tried the below codes which I found here in SO and none of them worked.

**Codes:**

```
string(//*[@colspan="3"])
/table/tr/td[@colspan=3]/following-sibling::td[1]
//tr/td[@colspan=3]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Not only the once above I tried many other Xpaths which were suggested here but was unable to get them to work.

Then I tried to get the once are not empty using something similar to the below one it also didn't give me any happy ending ;)

**Code**

```
/table/tr/td[text()='One']/following-sibling::td[1]
```

I need to figure this out but I'm currently stuck. Would it be possible for some one to unstuck me or give me some advice on what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, this xpath would help you to locate non-empty  elements, right?

```
//td[@style and (text() != '')]
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. That worked. Managed to combine your answer and the colspan part. Came up with this `//td[@colspan = '3' and (text() != '')]`  which worked the way I want it to work.